# Unable to store messages containing special characters

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to store the following tweet into MySQL database and it fails with the following exception. How do I fix it? Any help is appreciated. I am using utf8 charset database and I am thinking that `!???` in the message is being problematic here.

> tweet=I'm forbidden by a ride @ USS due to my height, I'm suppose to sit in the mid, incase there's an accident, but I still love my height!???

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\xF0\x9F...' for column 'message' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
```

Comment: I sense two possible issues. 1. the **'** and 2. **@**. Try to remove both from the string and try to save.

Comment: The ' seem more problematic to me.  What's your syntax for the update look like?  I'm betting you're using inline SQL which opens the door to SQL injection.  You should really use parameters instead.  It will eliminate your problem and improve the security of code.

Answer (score 2):

In your driver url path use the following parameters

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db>?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I tried that driver url but still i'm getting the same problem.